# How to find property name exists in soap ui response thats in Json

Tags: json, rest, soap

I am trying to figure out how to find if a particular property name exists in the Json response using Soap ui. For ex:

```
{"day_details": 
[{
"duration": "P0Y0M0DT9H17M",
"activities":    [
        {
     "crew_base": "NYP",
     "to_location": "NYP",
     "start_datetime": "2016-04-26T12:52:00-04:00",
     "end_datetime": "2016-04-26T16:30:00-04:00",
  },
    }
```

From the above code i need to find if "activities", Crew_base property name exists. I am not concern about the data or value it has. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just an FYI I am using basic Soap ui  not the pro version

Comment: You can use json slurper..